# execute junit test after server is up

Tags: junit

im new to junit , and i need to preform few tests as part of the build process 
that is when build is done , the server is started , and then i need to preform some unit tests on the server .
for example :
1. is server loaded the config xml
2. is server sended its massages to to nodes XYZ
the problem is i know how to make unit test on raw simple functions
but how do i preform such test that involved starting the server and trigger server inner functions ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a CI server as Hudson, Jenkins or similar. It is quite easy to configure a build that sets up a, say, Tomcat and then proceeds with a build script (maven, gradle, ant) that runs your tests against it. I suggest you make this part of your build pipe, and do not run this on a developers PC. These kinds of test do not scale well at all.

Comment: i have something like this , all the build is runes via Jenkins 
my question is how to run the junit after the server is up with ant

Comment: Use a build trigger. Once your server is up, trigger the test build job and run your tests against it.

Comment: what is : Use a build trigger?

Comment: Use "build after other projects are built" in Hudson, should be same in Jenkins.